# Convert all strings in a list to float. Works on single list but not when applied to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, floating-point, valueerror

I've got a dataframe `df_tweets` with geolocation. The geolocation is stored in a variable `geo_loc` as a string representation of a list. It looks like this:

```
# Geocode values are stored as objects/strings
df_tweets.geo_code[0]

#Output:
'[-4.241751 55.858303]'
```

I tested converting one row of `geo_code` to a list of longitude-latitude as floats:

```
# Converting string representation of list to list using strip and split 
# Can't use json.loads() or ast.literal_eval() because there's no comma delimiter

#--- Test with one tweet ----#

ini_list = df_tweets.geo_code[0]

# Converting string to list, but it will convert
# the lon and lat values to strings
# i.e. ['-4.241751', '55.858303']

results = ini_list.strip('][').split(' ') 

# So, we must convert string lon and lat to floats
results = list(map(float, results))

# printing final result and its type 
print ("final list", results) 
print (type(result))
```

This gives me:

```
# Output:
final list [-4.241751, 55.858303]
<class 'list'>
```

Success! Except no. I wrote it as a helper function:

```
def str_to_float_list(list_as_str):
  ''' 
  Function to convert a string representation
  of a list into a list of floats
  using strip and split, when you can't use json.loads() 
  or ast.literal_eval() because there's no comma delimiter

  Parameter:
  str_ = string representation of a list.  
  '''

  # Convert string to list
  str_list = list_as_str.strip('][').split(' ')

  # Convert strings inside list to float
  float_list = list(map(float, str_list[0]))

  return float_list
```

And when I run:

```
df_tweets['geocode'] = df_tweets['geo_code'].apply(str_to_float_list)
```

it gives me a `ValueError` when it encounters the minus `-` sign. I can't figure out why?! What am I missing?

Here's the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-c1035312dc12> in <module>()
     20 
     21 
---> 22 df_tweets['geocode'] = df_tweets['geo_code'].apply(str_to_float_list)

1 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-94-c1035312dc12> in str_to_float_list(list_as_str)
     15 
     16   # Convert strings inside list to float
---> 17   float_list = list(map(float, str_list[0]))
     18 
     19   return float_list

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

Comment: You have special character like '-' in your number ?, do try and except see which line return the error code

Comment: @YOandBEN_W yes, the minus sign of the longitude. But that wasn't a problem when running the code on a single list. So I'm not sure why, why applying to the whole column, is not letting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your line 17,

```
float_list = list(map(float, str_list[0]))
```

You do not need to reference the index. Pass the list the entire list, like this.

```
float_list = list(map(float, str_list))
```

The reason for this is str_list[0] is a string object, so it is trying to treat it like a list, and converting each value iteratively, starting with converting "-" to a float, then it would convert "4," etc.

Comment: That makes total sense. Solved the `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'` but is now  raising a `ValueError: could not convert string to float: `. Wonder if that's something to do with the space the original string has.But `str_list = list_as_str.strip('][').split(' ')` returns a list of two strings separated by a comma, so shouldn't be that. I'll update the question with your answer and the new error.

Comment: So I tried to replicate your code as best as I could, and passed "results" into a method. I got a different error, but it worked immediately when I removed the line "str_list = list_as_str.strip('][').split(' ')"

In your code for the method, are you passing that method the list like your variable "results," or are you passing it the preprocessed string? 
list(map(float,results)) should provide you the same list as float without helper method needed, I believe. Unless I am misunderstanding what's being passed

Comment: Thanks. Your comment made me check what is being passed. I did the following: 
```
lon_lat = []

# For each row in a variable

for row in df_tweets['geo_code']:
  # Convert string to list
  lon_lat = row.strip('][').split(' ')
  print (type(lon_lat))
  
  # Convert strings inside list to float
  lon_lat = list(map(float, lon_lat))
```
Got three `<class 'list'>` and then the Value Error. Issue is `df_tweets['geocode'][2]`. It has more than one space in between: `[-3.1798   51.497002]`. I could raise an exception for one, two and three spaces see how it goes.

Comment: Hm, yeah. There's a number of solutions to that. Assuming it never goes over 3 is one answer. You could use regex (not my favorite). A third would be preprocessing, which is what I would do personally, iterating all the values and making them consistent.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not the only one. Will have to go for preprocessing. Thanks for the help. Will mark your answer as solution since it does fix my original issue.

Comment: Just for the sake of closure, a quick change fixed it, from `str_list = list_as_str.strip('][').split(' ')` to  `str_list = ini_list.strip('][').split()`.  That removed all whitespace in between characters, regardless of length. Thanks again. @peter